# Maven Build Issues : Reading jacoco.exec file

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin, sonar-maven-plugin

We have several different faults with our `jacoco.exec` file, see the Error types below.

Can you please help us with this problem, we have at least 25% build failures due to `Jacoco`.

Error Type 1:

```
 09:18:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 09:18:17 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 09:18:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 09:18:17 [INFO] Total time: 02:02 min
 09:18:17 [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-22T09:18:17+01:00
 09:18:17 [INFO] Final Memory: 148M/2933M
 09:18:17 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 09:18:17 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project athena: Unable to read /repo/jenkins/production/workspace/CSW_All_Build_PreMerge-gate/support-functions/Common/target/jacoco.exec: malformed input around byte 2 -> [Help 1]
 09:18:17 [ERROR] 
 09:18:17 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 09:18:17 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 09:18:17 [ERROR]
```

Error type 2:

```
 11:44:13 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 11:44:13 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 11:44:13 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 11:44:13 [INFO] Total time: 02:04 min
 11:44:13 [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-21T11:44:14+01:00
 11:44:13 [INFO] Final Memory: 141M/3045M
 11:44:13 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 11:44:13 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project athena: Unable to read /repo/jenkins/production/workspace/CSW_All_Build_PreMerge-gate/support-functions/Common/target/jacoco.exec: Invalid execution data file. -> [Help 1]
 11:44:13 [ERROR] 
 11:44:13 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 11:44:13 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 11:44:13 [ERROR] 
 11:44:13 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 11:44:13 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 11:44:14 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
 11:44:14 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
```

Error type 3:

```
 14:33:23 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 14:33:23 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 14:33:23 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 14:33:23 [INFO] Total time: 01:51 min
 14:33:23 [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-21T14:33:23+01:00
 14:33:24 [INFO] Final Memory: 149M/2977M
 14:33:24 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 14:33:24 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project athena: Unable to read /repo/jenkins/production/workspace/CSW_All_Build_PreMerge-gate/support-functions/Common/target/jacoco.exec: Unknown block type 2d. -> [Help 1]
 14:33:24 [ERROR] 
 14:33:24 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 14:33:24 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 14:33:24 [ERROR] 
 14:33:24 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 14:33:24 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 14:33:24 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
 14:33:24 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
```

Versions:

- tried both jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128 and
  jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946  org.testng:6.9.9
- org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18
- org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1
- SonarQube 4.5.5  Sonar-maven-plugin 2.7.1

Comment: You are accessing the code coverage of jacoco via Sonar, so it's more a Sonar configuration issue and not maven. To get clear error details run the maven command with -X as explained in the error stack, copy the updated error to the post so that we can understand what's happening.